# SQL/Pyspark query to compre each value in a group with an aggregation of the same group

Tags: sql, pyspark, group-by, logic

Suppose I have a table like this

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/04 | 7 |
| 1 | 01/03 | 2 |
| 1 | 01/02 | 10 |
| 1 | 01/01 | 4 |
| 2 | 01/04 | 7 |
| 2 | 01/03 | 7 |
| 2 | 01/02 | 8 |
| 2 | 01/01 | 5 |

What I want to get is another table which the same number of records and that for each record has an extra column with the average value of the last `n` records with the same `id` that hast just dates before the given record. For example, if `n=2`, for the second row, with `id=1` and `date=01/03` I would like to have the value of the average of `value` in the two rows that have the same `id`and are just the two dates just before `01/03`, that is (10+4)/2=7. So, for this specific record, I would have:

| id | date | value | avg last 2 records same group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/04 | 7 | 6 |
| 1 | 01/03 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 01/02 | 10 | 4 |
| 1 | 01/01 | 4 | null |
| 2 | 01/04 | 7 | 7.5 |
| 2 | 01/03 | 7 | 6.5 |
| 2 | 01/02 | 8 | 5 |
| 2 | 01/01 | 5 | null |

My question is how to implement this in relational (SQL) logic (also implementations in Pyspark would help a lot).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with a [window function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html), partitioning by `id` and sorting by `date`.

### Setup

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '01/04', 7),
    (1, '01/03', 2),
    (1, '01/02', 10),
    (1, '01/01', 4),
    (2, '01/04', 7),
    (2, '01/03', 7),
    (2, '01/02', 8),
    (2, '01/01', 5)],
    ['id', 'date', 'value']
)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('sample_data')
```

### PySpark (dataframe API)

```
w = Window().partitionBy('id').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-2, -1)

df = df.withColumn('avg', F.avg('value').over(w))

df.orderBy(F.col('id').asc(), F.col('date').desc()).show()

+---+-----+-----+----+
| id| date|value| avg|
+---+-----+-----+----+
|  1|01/04|    7| 6.0|
|  1|01/03|    2| 7.0|
|  1|01/02|   10| 4.0|
|  1|01/01|    4|null|
|  2|01/04|    7| 7.5|
|  2|01/03|    7| 6.5|
|  2|01/02|    8| 5.0|
|  2|01/01|    5|null|
+---+-----+-----+----+
```

### SQL

```
spark.sql(
    '''
    SELECT
    id,
    date,
    value,
    AVG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS avg
    FROM sample_data
    ORDER BY id, date DESC
    ''').show()

+---+-----+-----+----+
| id| date|value| avg|
+---+-----+-----+----+
|  1|01/04|    7| 6.0|
|  1|01/03|    2| 7.0|
|  1|01/02|   10| 4.0|
|  1|01/01|    4|null|
|  2|01/04|    7| 7.5|
|  2|01/03|    7| 6.5|
|  2|01/02|    8| 5.0|
|  2|01/01|    5|null|
+---+-----+-----+----+
```